# Possible to use curl upload an external json file instead of --data?

Tags: json, rest, curl

When testing a REST POST api via curl, is it possible to send data from an external json file, instead of inline via `--data`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To specify the data from a file, use --data @filename. From man page of curl:

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl  to  read the data from stdin.  The contents of the file must already be URL-encoded. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar.